# if $\lim (a_nb_n) = \infty$ and $0<b_n<a_n$ for almost every $n$, then $\lim a_n =\infty$

Tags: calculus

Assume $\lim(a_nb_n) =\infty$.

Approve or disapprove:

> if $ 0 < b_n < a_n$ for almost every $n$, then $\lim a_n=\infty$

This is true, but I think I can disapprove it with this $a_n,b_n$:
\begin{cases}
    a_n =  2n \:\text{ if }n > 5, & \text{otherwise: } 1/n \\
    b_n =   n\:\text{ if }n > 5, & \text{otherwise: } n ^ 2
\end{cases}
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Please retype the equations with https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Your example is not a counterexample because indeed $a_n=2n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Since $0 < b_n < a_n $ for almost all $n$, i.e. for all $n > m$ for some fixed $m$, you know that $a_n > \sqrt{a_n b_n}$ for $n > m$, and since $\lim{a_n b_n} = \infty$, so is its squareroot and hence so is $a_n$

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "for almost every $n$" you mean the following more rigorous property, and that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, (b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are sequences of real numbers:

> If there exists an $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n>m$ it follows that $0<b_n<a_n$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_nb_n = \infty$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \infty$.

As a comment has pointed out, your choice of $a_n$ and $b_n$ doesn't disprove the theorem, as $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2n = \infty$.

Comment: Your counterexample doesn't obey $\lim{a_n b_n} = \infty$.

Comment: My bad. I replied when the OP was editing his question to MathJax formatting and missed that part of the theorem. Thanks for the correction, I will edit my answer now.